# Bind entire object in view to object in ViewModel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a UserProfile object in my ViewModel which contains many fields/properties such as first name, middle name, last name, etc. I am programming for iOS, so I am using fluent binding. I have been able to find out how to link the individual properties of the object in the View to the ViewModel, i.e.:

```
set.Bind(this._Profile).For(v => v.FirstName).To(vm => vm.UserProfile.FirstName);
```

This works fine, but I would like to be able to bind the entire object (so that I do not have to bind all fields individually). I have searched online, but I have had no luck. I tried:

```
set.Bind(this._Profile).For(v => v).To(vm => vm.UserProfile);
```

but that did not work. I am sure the answer is very simple, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If your View has a public `Profile` property:

```
   private User _profile ;
   public User Profile 
   {
       get { return _profile; } 
       set { 
          _profile = value; 
          // do UI updates here
       } 
   }
```

Then you can bind it using:

```
   set.Bind(this).For(v => v.Profile).To(vm => vm.UserProfile);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stuart, that did the trick.  Also, thank you very much for your helpful tutorials.  I am new to the MVVM architecture and C# app development, but your tutorials have made the learning process much easier.